# Updating matrix in c and overwriting it to a text file

Tags: c, matrix, file-handling

Firstly I'am new to C language and this is a part of the project I'am doing as my minor. My main objective is to read a matrix from text file and store it in 2D array and then take input from user, the particular row and column for which the value is to be updated in matrix and then overwrite the previous matrix stored in text file.
My text file consists of matrix in the form:

0 0 1 2 3 4...

0 0 2 0 3 0...

0 2 7 5 3 1...

.

.

.

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
        {
          int i;
          int j;
          int mat[31][200];

          FILE *file;
          file=fopen("uid.txt", "r");

          for(i = 0; i < 31; i++)
          {
              for(j = 0; j < 200; j++) 
              {

               if (!fscanf(file, "%d", &mat[i][j])) 
                   break;
              }
           }
        fclose(file);

        int col,value,row;
        printf("enter row");
        scanf("%d",&row);
        printf("enter col");
        scanf("%d",&col);
        printf("enter changed value");
        scanf("%d",&value);
        mat[row][col]=value;
        file=fopen("uid.txt", "w+");
        for(i = 0; i < 31; i++)
           {
              for(j = 0; j < 200; j++) 
              {
                fprintf(file,"%d ", mat[i][j]);
              }     
           fprintf(file,"\n");
           }
         fclose(file);
         }
```

But the values are not getting updated. Is there a way to update the matrix by using the same technique??

Comment: Check the return value from `fopen`. Also read the manual page from `scanf`

Comment: What is the input you give the program? When and where you do check the contents? Have the data been flushed to disk?

Comment: By the way, what happens if `fscanf` returns `EOF`? It *is* not equal to zero (which is what the `!` operator in your condition basically checks for).

Comment: I have tried again checking the return value from fopen. Still no changes